# 日本語に違和感:「信用度、バッジ、特権を獲得しました」

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

画面上部のメニューにマウスカーソルを合わせると、以下のようなポップアップテキストが表示されますが、この日本語に違和感があります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

翻訳案は以下です。
「獲得した信用度、バッジ、権利」

Answer (score 2, accepted):

案:

> 最近の実績：獲得した信用度・バッジ・権限

- <s>「最近」を追加: 全部は表示されないので</s>
- 権利→権限
- 単語の羅列なので、読点を中黒に

Comment: 「最近」は「最近の実績：」が前にあるので不要じゃないですかね？個人的には「最近の実績：獲得した信用度・バッジ・権限」が良い気がします。

Comment: @tomute おう、「最近の実績：」から後の文言についてだったのですね。「最近」は最初のだけでok、に賛成です。案を修正しました

Comment: すみません。私の書き方が分かりにくかったですね。

Comment: この回答の案は次回のビルドに適用予定です。